# CakePHP Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object (Controller)

Tags: cakephp, controller, php

I have CakePHP Controller code which is throwing up the following error 'Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object'.

The controller code is as follows:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->MonthlyReturn->create();
            $this->MonthlyReturn->saveField('company_id', $cid);    // Assign current company ID to this monthly return before saving
            if ($this->MonthlyReturn->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The monthly return has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The monthly return could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the first lines in your controllor?

Comment: `
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * MonthlyReturns Controller
 *
 * @property MonthlyReturn $MonthlyReturn
 */
class MonthlyReturnsController extends AppController {
 var $uses = array('Employee','Company');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define `$uses` inside your controller you need to explicitly load the `MonthlyReturn` model:

```
var $uses = array('MonthlyReturn','Employee','Company');
```

See [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html?highlight=uses#Controller%3a%3a%24uses)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that...Thanks, you saved me a lot of hassle!

Comment: A slight comment though, if Employee and Company are related to MonthlyReturn there's a better way to access them (without defining `$uses`). If they are related, you can access these models through `$this->MonthlyReturn->Employee` and `$this->MonthlyReturn->Company`, which is more the CakePHP way of doing things. I believe (somebody please correct me if I'm wrong) that when you load Employee and Company into the controller through `$uses` all related models will be loaded in those models as well (while they're already available within MontlyReturn) which increases memory load.

Answer (score 0):

you should load the model first like this

$this->loadModel("MonthlyReturn");

Here the MonthlyReturn is the name of the Model.